# BATCH FILE: File path from BACK slash to FORWARD slash ( \ to / )

Tags: batch-file, command, prompt

To begin with my knowledge on making batch files is limited at best but....

**I have:**

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  for /f  "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.txt *.res'
  ) do (
    set "$Path=%%a"
    set $path=!$path:%cd%=!
    echo !$path:~1!
  )
)>MapResource.res
```

**Which outputs:**

```
Sample.wad  
Folder1\sample.wav  
Folder1\Folder2\sample.mdl
```

**I want:**

```
Sample.wad  
Folder1/sample.wav
Folder1/Folder2/sample.mdl
```

What would I need to incorporate into my exiting coding to make my BACK slashes become FORWARD slashes within my coding?

I know this is an odd request but the application I am attempting to utilize this with annoyingly requires forward slashes, which granted I could manually use the replace allfunction in note pad to accomplish this but would be very tedious for the task I am attempting to do.

Thanks!

Comment: The application that is going to be utilizing the resource file generated requires forward slashes. Granted I could utilize the replace function to manually replace all of the back slashes with forward slashes but it is extremely tedious so I am hoping for a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using search and replace to remove the current directory from the file path to yield a relative path. Just use another search and replace to convert `\` into `/`.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
  for /f  "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.txt *.res'
  ) do (
    set "$Path=%%a"
    set "$path=!$path:%cd%=!"
    set "$Path=!$Path:\=/!"
    echo !$path:~1!
  )
)>MapResource.res
```

Comment: Wow, a HUGE thank you for not only correcting my formatting (didn't seem to want to copy right) but for the help. I didn't realize the answer was a lot simpler than I thought. A HUGE thanks again. :-)